# Texturing - Best approach to apply textures from photos

Tags: texturing, uv, image, uv-image-editor

I'm modeling a piece of furniture that I have in my house, so I have full access to the model. I'm starting with Blender only for a couple of weeks so I started with simple geometric forms.

My question is related with texturing. I really wanted to mimic the look of the furniture that I have so, what is the best way to extract those textures from photos? Or, how to take those photos? Is there any kind of software to help preparing these textures? Or is this approach the wrong one? Should I use generic textures?

It seems these are many questions but I think it's all related.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

[image]

UPDATE:

[image]

Comment: Creating textures from photos can be a pretty complex topic. In general you want to have flat lighting with no shading or specular highlights (since that will be added by the render engine depending on the 3d scene). See [here](http://photography.tutsplus.com/tutorials/12-tips-tricks-for-shooting-great-textures-and-a-free-texture-pack--photo-5373) and [here](http://www.3dbuzz.com/forum/threads/171858-Best-way-to-photograph-textures). It might be easier to just grab something off [textures.com](http://www.textures.com/browse/fine-wood/14119).

Comment: There's a great video by Bartek Skorupa that will give you lots of ideas: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kAUmLcXhUj0&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by Greg Zaal taking photos to use in textures can be full time project on it's own, especially if you want to take the time to make them reusable elsewhere in other projects, which frankly is the only situation I would see it being worth the trouble to make new textures from scratch.

As mentioned, textures should have as generic as possible lighting as to avoid visible shadows, lighting gradients and shading artifacts that would ruin tiling, an no reflections at all, since those will be added by the software from the virtual 3D scene at render time.

Besides that if you want them to have any value besides the very specific scope of the current project, reusable wood textures are generally desired to be tileable or repeatable. That means they are edited in image editing software in specific ways so they can be repeated side by side without noticeable seams or borders and avoiding repeating patterns.

So unless for some reason you want a very very realistic, down to specific wood features in the right places, and very true to the original recreation of your furniture (which is a perfectly valid goal, if that is what you want) I would recommend downloading some "off the shelf" generic textures from the internet.
There are plenty good quality tileable textures everywhere, I am sure you can find some that suit your need, with the same wood type or one that is similar enough.

One other desirable alternative you may be interested in, since your goal seems to be learning Blender, is to go the procedural way and try to use computer generated materials and textures which can have a high reuse value.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. For the furniture I used a free texture on some site and, for a beginner like me, I'm happy with the results. For the mosaics on the wall, I have the same problem but, in a related question, is there a way to easily correct the difference in brightness between the top and bottom rows and the rest of the mosaics?

Comment: I had a technique to do that can't quite remember how it went anymore, it's been a while since I last used it. I think was something like opening photo in an image editing software, duplicating the image as a new layer, inverting it's color, then then changing it's opacity and blending mode. I'm not sure what the blending mode was anymore though, try a few different ones and see which works best.